# Allowing sudo kill for remote user for recovery purpose. Security implications?

Tags: linux, security, sudo

I'm planning to create user allowed to SSH in and with right to `sudo kill` in case something disables local terminal/keyboard/display etc. Would probably add `ps` and/or `htop` to the list, as well. I would really like to give `lsof` rights as well but I'm pretty sure that'd be poor policy.

Now, this isn't production box, per se, and nobody cares enough to try and break in. But I'm looking to understand the dynamics of computer security and doing poor security decisions isn't the way to go about it.

Are there any non-obvious implications of allowing `kill`, `ps`, `htop` and `shutdown` sudo rights for remote user, assuming remote machine is less secure than localhost?

Crashing live system and forcing logout is fine. Whether it's possible to prevent reboot or, worse, escalate privileges somehow is what I'm really asking.

Any insight is appreciated.

The box in question is gentoo, non-systemd in case that matters.

PS. since this is decidedly Linux question I asked it here but will move it to Infosec if it's preferred.